Uploading file to s3 with formidable
I have a complex form with multiple fields and a .tif file I retrieve in my server side in NextJS.
I had a previous module that did not work well as I was no longer able to open the images after the were upload on the s3
function parseFormData(body: Buffer, boundary: string) {
  const parts = body.toString().split(`--${boundary}`);
  const dataPart = parts.find((part) =>
    part.includes('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"')
  );
  const filePart = parts.find((part) =>
    part.includes('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"')
  );
  if (!filePart || !dataPart) {
    throw new Error("Data or file not found in the request");
  }
  const fileStart = filePart.indexOf("\r\n\r\n") + 4;
  const buffer = Buffer.from(filePart.substring(fileStart), "binary");
  const dataStart = dataPart.indexOf("\r\n\r\n") + 4;
  const formData = JSON.parse(dataPart.substring(dataStart).trim()) as FormData;
  const filenameMatch = filePart.match(/filename="(.+?)"/);
  const filename = filenameMatch && filenameMatch[1] ? filenameMatch[1] : "img";
  return { buffer, formData, filename };
}

I am trying to convert my file in a stream so I can upload it easily on my s3 but formidable seems to make my task tremendously difficult.
function parseForm(req: NextApiRequest): Promise<{ fields: any; files: any }> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = formidable({
      multiples: false,
      fileWriteStreamHandler: () => {
        const pass = new Readable();
        pass._read = () => {};
        return pass;
      },
    });
    form.parse(req, (err: string, fields: Fields, files: Files) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve({ fields, files });
    });
  });
}

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const { fields, files } = await parseForm(req);

      const file = files.file;
      if (!file) {
        throw new Error("File is missing !");
      }
      const stream = Readable.from(file) as Readable;
      const formData = fields as FormData;
      const filename = file.originalFilename;

      const clientId = await verifyClientKey(formData.client);

      if (!clientId) {
        console.error("Error : no client");
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "ID missing" });
      }

      await uploadToS3(stream, filename, file.mimetype);

      const commande = await insertIntoDatabase(formData, clientId);

      res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: commande });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        "Error while inserting data in database",
        error
      );
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: "Something went wrong with the server" });
    }
    req.on("error", (err) => {
      console.error("Error when recieving the request:", err);
      res
        .status(500)
        .json({ success: false, message: "Error during file upload" });
    });
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", ["POST"]);
    res.status(405).end(`Unauthorized method ${req.method}`);
  }
}

How can I upload my file to s3 with or without formidable ?
